# publish vs searchable by employers

Tags: support, jobs, search

what is the difference between publishing my CV and having it be searchable by employers?

they are two different options/steps. one says "Your CV is searchable by employers".. the other says "Your CV is unpublished".. what does publishing do above and beyond the "searchable" part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About $29 and having employers [pull you up in their search results and contact you directly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29023/contact-between-employers-and-candidates). [Well, until 23:59 PST.](http://twitter.com/codinghorror/statuses/5573078014) Then [it's about a $99](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq) difference.

Regarding `Publish` vs `Search`:

If your CV is '`published`' that means it's open to the public to see. If it's not published, it can show up in Employer search results but is not visible to the outside world.

Comment: I assume you are describing the "searchable by employers" part. they are two different options/steps. one says "Your CV is searchable by employers".. the other says "Your CV is unpublished".. what does publishing do above and beyond the "searchable" part? I did pay the $29.

Comment: If your CV is 'published' that means it's open to the public to see. If it's unpublished, then the public cannot see it but Employers can.

Comment: does 'published' also mean that it will be indexed by search engines, or is it 'public' only in the sense that people on stackoverflow can see it?

Comment: public means just that. Public. As in The eyes of the intertubez are on you. Google can only see if it's crawl-able.  If it's 'private' or 'unpublished' then it will only show up on the stack Overflow search that employers conduct.

Answer (score 1):

**Published** -- visible to the world, Google, your Mom, your friends, everyone on the planet

**Filed** -- eligible for appearance in private employer search results (though this can be toggled on and off at will)

Comment: So the free CVs aren't searchable from the regular SO search box, or google? But are just hosted on the site?

Or do you mean that only paid for CVs are searched by recruiters ?